# Unity Netcode ServerRpc not being called

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm using Unity's Netcode for GameObjects, and I can't see a reason why this isn't working. I use Rpcs in the rest of my project, but this doesn't seem any different from that. Any help would be appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class TestOnline : NetworkBehaviour
{

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        TestServerRpc();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    void TestServerRpc()
    {
        Debug.Log("This isn't being printed");
    }
}
```

This code should cause the host of the lobby to print in the log when the scene is loaded.

Comment: I've found the solution. I moved the script's GameObject into the same scene that sets up the online lobby, with it 'DontDestroyOnLoad'. Then it activates the GameObject when the required scene is open. Hope this helps!